# How to change refs from one child component to other child component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, chat

I am working on a chating app with reactjs and i have my components as:

```
-ChatBox
      |-MessageList
      |-InputArea
```

I want to update(re-render,basically append a "li" and scroll down automatically) MessageList component if user provides an input from Input Area.
What i have thought so far is to pass ref from chatbox to MessageList and and then use those refs in InputArea. But i think it is not a good approach. Can someone suggest me what to do.

Update:

My MessageList code:

```
import React, { useContext,useRef, useState, useEffect } from 'react';

import Message from './Message';

import "./MessageList.css";
import { AuthContext } from '../../Shared/Context/AuthContext';

const MESSAGES=[{convId:1, msgId:1 ,from:'u1',to:'u2',msg:"hello"},
{convId:1, msgId:2 ,from:'u2',to:'u1',msg:"hi"},
{convId:1, msgId:3 ,from:'u1',to:'u2',msg:"how ru"},
{convId:1, msgId:4 ,from:'u2',to:'u1',msg:"goood!!!"},
{convId:1, msgId:5 ,from:'u1',to:'u2',msg:"party ?!"},
{convId:1, msgId:6 ,from:'u2',to:'u1',msg:"yeah!!!"}];

const MessageList=(props)=>{
    const msgBoxRef=useRef();
    const [messages,setMessages]=useState(MESSAGES);

    useEffect(()=>{
        msgBoxRef.current.scrollTop=msgBoxRef.current.scrollHeight;

    },[messages]);

    useEffect(()=>{
        if(msgBoxRef.current.scrollTop===msgBoxRef.current.scrollHeight)
            msgBoxRef.current.scrollTop=msgBoxRef.current.scrollHeight;
    },[])

    const auth =useContext(AuthContext);
    return (<div className="messages" ref={msgBoxRef}>
        <ul>
            {messages.map((msg)=>(
                    <Message key={msg.msgId} className={(msg.from===auth.user.userName)?"sent":"replies"} imageSrc="http://emilcarlsson.se/assets/mikeross.png">{msg.msg}</Message>
            ))}
        </ul>
    </div>);
};

export default MessageList;
```

Input Component code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {InputGroup,FormControl,Button} from 'react-bootstrap';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faPaperPlane } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";

const Input=(props)=>{
    return (<InputGroup className="mb-0">
    <FormControl className="input-msg shadow-none" placeholder="Enter new message..." aria-label="new task" />
    <InputGroup.Append>
      <Button className="send-btn shadow-none">
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPaperPlane} />
      </Button>
    </InputGroup.Append>
  </InputGroup>);
};


export default Input;
```

ChatBox code:

```
//TODO: IMPLEMENT CHAT CARD
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import { Card } from "react-bootstrap";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faArrowLeft } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";

import MessageList from "./MessageList";
import Input from "./Input";
import Conversations from "./Conversations";

import "./ChatBox.css";

const ChatBox = (props) => {
  const [conversation, setConversation] = useState(null);
  const [backBtn,setBackBtn]=useState(false);
  const selectedConv = (profile) => {
    setConversation(profile);
    setBackBtn(true);
  };
  const backBtnHandler=()=>{
    setConversation(null);
    setBackBtn(false);
  }


  return (
    <Card className="frame">
      {conversation ? (
        <React.Fragment>
          <Card.Header><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faArrowLeft} onClick={backBtnHandler}/>{" "+conversation.name}</Card.Header>
          <MessageList chatId={conversation.id}/>
          <Input />
        </React.Fragment>
      ) : (
        <React.Fragment>
          <Card.Header>Chatbox</Card.Header>
          <Conversations selectedChat={selectedConv} />
        </React.Fragment>
      )}
    </Card>
  );
};

export default ChatBox;
```

Comment: Maybe it helps if you post some code

Comment: @Lhew i've made changes, see if you can help now.

Comment: Have you tried the element.current.scrollIntoView()? 

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

Comment: problem is not how to scroll,i want to know where and how to code that feature which sends message to Messagelist from Input component and then scroll to bottom